# Varargs method modifies caller's array instead of its own copy?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I have this simple varargs method which divides each item in the list:

```
import java.util.*;
class A {
    static long f(long... xs) {
      Arrays.sort(xs);
      long y = 100000000;
      for (int i = xs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        y /= xs[i];
      return y;
    }
    static {
        System.out.println(f(5,2,6,3,9,3,13,4,5));
        long[] xs = new long[]{5,2,6,3,9,3,13,4,5};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(xs));
        System.out.println(f(xs));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(xs));
    }
}
```

I'd expect it to pass a copy of the array, but apparently it's somehow modifying the array I pass in, instead of its own local copy:

```
$ javac A.java && java A
79
[5, 2, 6, 3, 9, 3, 13, 4, 5]
79
[2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 9, 13]
```

So I wrote this simple test program:

```
class B {
    static void f(Object... os) {
        System.out.println(os);
    }
    static {
        Object os = new Object[]{1,2,3};
        System.out.println(os);
        f(os);
    }
}
```

And it does what I expect, it clones the object array before passing it into `f` (hence different object identifiers):

```
$ javac B.java && java B
[Ljava.lang.Object;@1242719c
[Ljava.lang.Object;@4830c221
```

So how then is `f` in `A` modifying the caller's array instead of its own copy?

Comment: Java copies references by value. It never copies or clones objects nor arrays as arguments (or any other situation) unless you do it explicitly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like you've tricked yourself here:

```
Object os = new Object[]{1,2,3};
System.out.println(os);
f(os);
```

Since `os` is typed as `Object`, it gets interpreted as the first element of the varargs array. What gets passed into the method is actually a new `Object[]` whose single element is your `Object[]`.

If you do the following, it will print the same instance:

```
Object[] os = new Object[]{1,2,3};
System.out.println(os);
f(os);
```

The `f` method will need make a defensive copy of the array itself in order to guarantee that an array passed in by the caller isn't modified. As arshajii points out, varargs are *foremost* array parameters, with the "bonus" behavior of creating a new array when given an argument list.

Anyway you can use [`Arrays.copyOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28long%5B%5D,%20int%29) to make the copy, which delegates to (the less type-safe) [`System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29).

Comment: +1 Good catch. It's worth mentioning that a varargs method is *exactly* the same as an equivalent method that takes an array parameter except that when you pass multiple arguments to the varargs method, an array is created for you.

Answer (score 3):

varargs *is* an array type, but with syntactic sugar to allow an on-the-fly array creation if elements are passed separately as parameters.

That is, these two signatures are identical:

```
static long f(long... xs) {
static long f(long[] xs) {
```

Except that the varargs may be called with separate elements instead of an array

Of course the array will get modified if you bypass the on-the-fly creation and create an array yourself to pass in.

Answer (score 1):

> So how then is f in A modifying the caller's array instead of its own copy?

It doesn't have its own copy. It has a reference to the caller's array.

Answer (score -1):

In the end, an array is an object, so you don't modify the array reference itself instead its contents which is allowed.

Comment: Yes, but he modifies the contents of a different array. And these are primitives, which don't have references.

Comment: @f1sh OP's modifying the array values in the method, so after calling it on the array its contents will be modified.